# Why NumPy creates a view for x[[slice(None), 1, 2]]

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

In NumPy documentation for [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), it is mentioned that

> Also recognize that `x[[1, 2, 3]]` will trigger advanced indexing, whereas `x[[1, 2, slice(None)]]` will trigger basic slicing.

A matrix is stored sequentially into the memory. I understand that it makes sense to make a view of `x[[1, 2, slice(None)]]` since the elements are stored sequentially into the memory. But why Numpy returns a view of `x[[1, slice(None), 2]]` or `x[[slice(None), 1, 2]]`. For instance, assume

```
x = [[[ 0,  1,  2],
      [ 3,  4,  5],
      [ 6,  7,  8]],
     [[ 9, 10, 11],
      [12, 13, 14],
      [15, 16, 17]],
     [[18, 19, 20],
      [21, 22, 23],
      [24, 25, 26]]]
```

`x[[1, slice(None), 2]]` returns a view of `[11, 14, 17]` which is not sequentially stored in the memory as well as for `x[[slice(None), 1, 2]]` which returns `[5, 14, 23]`.

I would like to know

1. Why NumPy even returns a view in these two cases
2. How NumPy handles memory addressing to create these views

Comment: This is a bad example - `x[[slice(None), 1, 2]]` is deprecated as of 1.15, and should be spelt `x[slice(None), 1, 2]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [SciPy cookbook](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html):

> The rule of thumb for creating a slice view is that the viewed elements can be addressed with offsets, strides, and counts in the original array.

When you have an indexing like `x[[1, slice(None), 2]]`, you get a view because slicing an entire axis allows for a certain offset, stride and count to represent the slice with the original array.

For instance, with `x = np.arange(27).reshape(3, 3, 3).copy()`, we have:

```
In [79]: x_view = x[1, :, 2]  # or equivalently x[[1, slice(None), 2]]

In [80]: x_view
Out[80]: array([11, 14, 17])

In [81]: x_view.base
Out[81]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

Then we can use [`numpy.byte_bounds`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/utils.py#L186) (not part of the public API, YMMV) to illustrate the offset to get our slice from our original array.

```
In [82]: np.byte_bounds(x_view)[0] - np.byte_bounds(x_view.base)[0]
Out[82]: 88
```

This makes sense, since there are 11 8-byte integers before the first value in the slice, 11. NumPy calculates this offset with a formula you can [see here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#internal-memory-layout-of-an-ndarray), using the strides of the original array.

```
In [93]: (x.strides * np.array([1, 0, 2])).sum()
Out[93]: 88
```

The strides in our slice simply become whatever the strides were for `x` along the axis (or axes) on which we are slicing. i.e. `x.strides[1] == x_view.strides[0]`. Now together the offset, new strides and count are enough information for NumPy to view our slice from our original array.

```
In [94]: x_view.strides
Out[94]: (24,)

In [95]: x_view.size
Out[95]: 3
```

Finally, the reason why you trigger fancy indexing with `x[[0, 1, 2]]` for instance is because in the absence of a full axis slice, it isn't generally possible to formulate some new offset, byte order, strides and count such that we can view the slice with the same underlying data.

Comment: thanks for a thorough explanation. My notion of view was that once the memory reference address of the first element is known (offset), the rest are retrieved incrementally (one by one not by the strides). For instance for `x_view = [11, 14, 17]`, my notion of view is no longer valid since 11, 14 and 17 are not stored in the memory incrementally. But your answer explained clearly the mechanism of Numpy creating views.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use `__array_interface__` to examine the attributes of an array:

With your `x`:

```
In [51]: x.__array_interface__
Out[51]: 
{'data': (43241792, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (3, 3, 3),
 'version': 3}
In [52]: x.strides
Out[52]: (72, 24, 8)
```

It's a (3,3,3) array.  The last axis can be scanned by stepping 8 bytes at a time, the size of `x.itemsize`.  3*8 steps rows, and 3*3*8 steps through the planes (1st dim).

```
In [53]: y = x[:,1,2]
In [54]: y.shape
Out[54]: (3,)
In [55]: y.strides
Out[55]: (72,)
In [56]: y.__array_interface__['data']
Out[56]: (43241832, False)
```

`y` elements can addressed by stepping by planes, 3*3*8.  43241832 is the starting point, 40 bytes into the data buffer, 5*8

```
In [59]: y
Out[59]: array([ 5, 14, 23])
```

So it starts at the 5th element, and steps forward one plane at a time (9 elements), for a total of 3 elements.

The fact that `y.__array_interface__['data']` falls within the range of the `x` 'data' tells me that `y` is a view.  It's a view because a combination of this buffer starting point, the strides and the shape let us access all the values of `y`.

With advanced indexing it isn't possible to (in general) to access the elements with these simple parameters, so `numpy` has to make a copy of the data.

---

A reversed view is possible by just changing the strides and 'data' start point:

```
In [60]: z = y[::-1]
In [61]: z.__array_interface__
Out[61]: 
{'data': (43241976, False),
 'strides': (-72,),
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (3,),
 'version': 3}
```

Transpose also changes strides:

```
In [62]: x.T.strides
Out[62]: (8, 24, 72)
```

Comment: thanks for this tip. I actually examined the _base_ and the _view_ by `__array_interface__` earlier myself. I simply did not understand why Numpy would even create a view in case of my question. But what you explained here I find extremely useful. Please also have a look at my comment I left in the answer